# Can Django display data from multiple tables (Models/Classes) on a single page?

Tags: python, html, django

This is based on the Django Tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) to build a "Polls" app.

It's essentially a Question model and a Choice model. The Choice model is linked to Question through a foreign key (named 'question').

After completion of the tutorial, I thought I'd try to add a specific functionality to the app:

On a single html page, display a list of all the questions, with their associated choices underneath each question. (Displaying the number of votes for each choice as well would be a plus but not necessary at this point.)

[Something like this would be an ideal page display.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIE8V.png)

Right now, I can display ALL questions (with NO choices) on a page

-OR-

ONE question with ALL associated choices on a page.

I cannot seem to display ALL the questions AND their choices on a single page.

The below is based on the similar questions and responses I could find as well as the djangoproject.com documentation.

models.py:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    <...etc: additional code here about pub_date...>
    
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

To populate the queryset with the instances I want, I've tried both a Class-based view (& variations), and a Function-based view (& variations).
(I have the least confidence in the Class-based attempt. I'll post it if anyone wants to see it.)

The Function-based view approach:

view.py:

```
def func_allreslt(request):
    context = {}
    context["question"] = Question.objects.all()
    context["choice"] = Choice.objects.all()

    return render(request, "polls/funcallreslt.html", context)
```

funcallreslt.html:

```html
<ul>
  {% for question in context %}
  <li> {{question.question_text }} </li>
  <ol type=1>
    {% for choice in context %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ol>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I've also tried using various combinations of prefetch_related and/or select_related. I can offer that code if anyone's interested.

(I'm still using .all() without any filtering or slicing because the db currently holds 4 questions and about 13 choices total, so I didn't figure it was necessary to cut down on what's being retrieved yet.)

Can anyone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

(After this I thought I might go through and build a series of if/then statements to see if I could list the results through that logic.

Another road I thought about was writing it out as an SQL query and then seeing if I could get Django to use the results.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add the `Choices` to the context. You add the `Question` queryset and inside the template you render the associated `Choices`:

```
def func_allreslt(request):
    context = {}
    context["questions"] = Question.objects.all()
    return render(request, "polls/funcallreslt.html", context)
```

And inside your template:

```
<ul>
  {% for question in questions %}
  <li> {{question.question_text }} </li>
  <ol type=1>
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ol>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```